# Handling an exception thrown from ExceptionHandler in a filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My logic was to implement a global exception filter which handles any exception inside my Spring MVC, and also has `@ControllerAdvice` to Handle exception

**Global Filter**

```
@Component
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**Controller Advice**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class BaseController {
   @ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
   public void handlePersistenceException(ConstraintViolationException ex, HttpServletRequest request) throws MyException {
     String str = "";

     for (ConstraintViolation constraintViolation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
       str += "Property '" + constraintViolation.getPropertyPath() + "' - " + constraintViolation.getMessage();
     }

     MyException myException = new MyException(str);
     throw myException;
  }
}
```

The globalfilter wraps the execution of the exception so it captures the ConstraintViolation.
But my logic needs to modify the `ConstraintViolation` as `MyException` and throw it from ControllerAdvice. The global still captures the ConstraintViolation, not the MyException which is thrown from ControllerAdvice, but the exception is not carried over to the filter when I am not throwing MyException.

How to override the ConstraintViolationException with MyException in ControllerAdvice to make it captured by the globalexception filter.

Comment: are other `@ExceptionHandler`s working in `BaseController` class?

Comment: Check if you are handling MyException in any `@ControllerAdivce`s. Also why is BaseController both, a `@Controller` and a `@ControllerAdvice`?

Comment: @anchreg Oh its a mistake I included both in this snippet

Comment: Could you provide the code you've written inside `handlePersistenceException`?

Comment: @anchreg I want to abstract with my message added the logic.

Comment: I guess the problem is the filters order. How do you add the `GlobalExceptionHandlerFilter `? It should be added **before** `ControllerAdvice` to wrap the chain

Comment: @StanislavL The GloblalExceptionHandlerFilter is added before Controller Advice

Comment: How do you check this? Any logs? Breakpoints in the filters?

Comment: @StanislavL Using break points and logs

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your MyException class in ResponseEntity and return it with the required HttpStatus.

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<MyException> notFoundException(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {


    MyException myException = new MyException("CustomMessage");
    logger.error("An constrain voilation occured reason {}", e);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(myException , HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is looking for

Comment: This is a response so it bypasses the global filter but my logic need to throw an exception.

Comment: @GautamNaik yes we can but the filter contains the global logic to handle MyException, in your case I have to repeat same thing again for all the ExceptionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve the above required scenario, as the ExceptionHandler [invoker](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.html#doResolveHandlerMethodException(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod,%20java.lang.Exception))(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException) which invokes the method binded with the perfect match for the exception catches any exception from the invoked method.

The default action in this chain incase of exception in handler is to rethrow the original Exception which invoked the handler.